# Getting error in add items in a list in office 365

Tags: office-365

I have used the below code for adding items in a sharepoint list in office 365.
Below the line :

```
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
```

whereever oListItem is used am getting an error saying oListItem is undefined. I found this code in a microsoft site. But still am getting an error.

Any advice is appreciated.

got the code from the below URL:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8f2a912b-88b8-42b7-b187-c2a6039bf97d/using-javascript-to-add-an-item-to-a-sharepoint-list.

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function createListItem() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
 var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(' Participant ');

var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
 this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

  oListItem.set_item('Title', 'New Item!');

 oListItem.update();

clientContext.load(oListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
 }

function onQuerySucceeded() {

alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
 }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }
```

Comment: I think the problem may be because of spaces in the list tile. Can you trying removing the spaces in it. .getByTitle('Participant')

Comment: I just ran into this except on the line after. Any resolution here?